# Does implementing Angular Service Worker into Angular App lower Firestore Read counts for my website?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-service-worker

My Website displays menu-items which are stored in Firestore as separate documents.

menu

---menu-item({'name' : name_1, 'price' : price_1})

---menu-item({'name' : name_1, 'price' : price_1})

Angular.io notes:  "At its simplest, a service worker is a script that runs in the web browser and manages caching for an application"

This seems to me that Angular App will keep on using cached data unless connection is broken or firestore data is changed hence resulting less firestore reads...?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation regarding [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For the web, offline persistence is an experimental feature that is supported only by the Chrome, Safari, and Firefox web browsers. Also, if a user opens multiple browser tabs that point to the same Cloud Firestore database, and offline persistence is enabled, Cloud Firestore will work correctly only in the first tab.

So with other words, if you are using a single tab and the data isn't changed in the database, the results are coming from cache, which also means less Firestore reads for that particular query.